# Counting leaves in a binary tree without using if condition

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree, polymorphism

I know that there is a generic algorithm which counts the number of leaves recursive by checking if a node doesn't have left and right child. But I want to write the same code using polymorphic code and check whether its possible or not, right now I am stuck checking for the leaf condition but that information doesn't depend totally on the current node, below is my code implemented till now:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


abstract class Tree {
  abstract int count();
}

class Empty extends Tree {
  public int count() {
    return 0;   
  }
}

class NonEmpty extends Tree {

  private final int val;
  private final Tree left;
  private final Tree right;

  public NonEmpty(int val, Tree left, Tree right) {
    this.val   = val;
    this.left  = left;
    this.right = right;
  }

  public int count() {
    return left.count() + right.count();
  }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Tree t = new NonEmpty(5, new Empty(), new Empty());
    System.out.println(t.count()); // 0 but should be 1
  }
}
```

**Update 1**

I discussed this idea with few of my colleagues I got a lot of criticism, so is this a bad idea? my view is it feels clean to me, I would like to hear opinion of others.

Comment: Is it possible to re-organize your subclasses? Like make Leaf/Branch subclasses instead of Empty/NonEmpty?

Comment: @friendlydog if you can show me that it could be possible by your version of code then yes I am interested but it will be good if it can be implemented this way.

Comment: The number of leaves in in some Tree rooted at R is either 1, if R is a leaf or the sum of the number of leaves of the children of R. Because of this, it is necessary to be able to determine whether a particular node is a leaf. This can be done through type (as suggested by @friendlydog), or by some other determination such as checking child types (both empty), checking total number of leaves of children (total 0 implies that this is a leaf).

Comment: Empty's count should be 1 and the count of your exemple should be 2 (your comment on last line of code). @CodeYogi of course it can be implemented this way, this is exactly what subtyping polymorphism is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Finally fixed solution:**

```
interface Tree {
    Tree NULL_TREE = new NullTree();

    int countLeafs();
    Tree left();
    Tree right();
}

class NullTree implements Tree {
    @Override
    public int countLeafs() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Tree left() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Tree right() {
        return this;
    }
}

class Leaf implements Tree {
    private int val;

    public Leaf(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public int countLeafs() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Tree left() {
        return NULL_TREE;
    }

    @Override
    public Tree right() {
        return NULL_TREE;
    }
}

class Node implements Tree {

    private final int val;
    private final Tree left;
    private final Tree right;

    public Node(int val, Tree left, Tree right) {
        this.val = val;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    @Override
    public int countLeafs() {
        return left.countLeafs() + right.countLeafs();
    }

    @Override
    public Tree left() {
        return left;
    }

    @Override
    public Tree right() {
        return right;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Tree t = new Node(5, new Leaf(10), new Leaf(20));
        System.out.println(t.countLeafs());
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong solution see my comments to another answer.

Comment: @CodeYogi As stackoverflow is highly mutable, your reference to "another answer" doesn't seem to make any sense at this time. Can you also explain here what the problem is?

Comment: The above code will count all the nodes not just leaves.

Comment: @CodeYogi, Is it ok now ? :)

Comment: @KonstantinLabun seems a clever solution to me but I would for some time to see what other to say.

Comment: But you know that ?: is just if/then/else in disguise?

Comment: @GhostCat ya tha's why I was not sure about it.

Comment: @KonstantinLabun you third solution seems good to me OO wise but its not the standard definition of the tree i.e. a tree can be either null or it can have a node and left and right child. I am still open to answers because its a kind of finding.

Comment: @CodeYogi, fixed.. :)

Comment: @KonstantinLabun your fourth solution is by far the most deserving one.

Comment: @GhostCat **NO**, no if in disguise! This is subtyping polymorphism, seems magical but not.

Comment: @KonstantinLabun Hint: What is the point of having your whole "edit" history in your answer? Why don't you reduce it to the actual "final" content that you want to provide?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Sure, I saw the attempts for polymorphism. All I am saying is: if the code still has ?: inside, then it is not "completely" if-free. But it looks like the final code is.

Comment: @GhostCat , the point was to save other thoughts and solutions. But, yes, they were not fully right and history become too long.. Thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
public int count() {
    return left.count() + right.count();
}
```

to

```
public int count() {
    return Math.max(1, left.count() + right.count());
}
```

This is similar to [Konstantin's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39072205/2) involving a conditional expression: if `left.count() + right.count()` is 0, then it is a leaf and its count should be 1.

(edit: I removed the rest since it had too many caveats and elimnating them would be more complicated than it's worth.)

Comment: Nice idea with `Math.max(1, left.count() + right.count());`, I just think about it too :)

Comment: Yes, I agree it seems to be a more OO approach, I am talking about `Math.max` because finding maximum is again an abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's have another class called Branch, as @[friendlydog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6732794/friendly-dog) suggested:

```
abstract class Tree {
  abstract int count();
}

class Empty extends Tree {
  public int count() {
    return 0;   
  }
}

class NonEmpty extends Tree{
    private final int val;

    public NonEmpty(int val){
        this.val=val;
    }

    public int count(){
        return 1;
    }
}

class Branch extends Tree {

  private final int val;
  private final Tree left;
  private final Tree right;

  public Branch(int val, Tree left, Tree right) {
    this.val   = val;
    this.left  = left;
    this.right = right;
  }


  public int count() {
    return 1+left.count() + right.count(); // to count all non-empty nodes
    //return left.count()+right.count(); //to count only leaves;
  }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Tree t = new Branch(5, new Empty(), new Empty());
    System.out.println(t.count()); // now it's 1 :)
  }
}
```

For an even nicer solution, you can have 2 more constructors on `Branch`: one with just the `val`, padding the `left` and `right` with `Empty`, and another with `val` and non-`Empty` `left`, padding only `right`.

Answer (score 1):

The answers I've seen so far assume that you either have a leaf or a node that has *both* a left and a right child. Here's an approach that can handle any of the children missing:

```
class Tree {
    final Optional<Tree> left;
    final Optional<Tree> right;

    Tree(Optional<Tree> left, Optional<Tree> right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    int leafCount() {
        return left.map(Tree::leafCount)
                .map(l -> right.map(Tree::leafCount).map(r -> l + r).orElse(l))
                .orElse(right.map(Tree:leafCount).orElse(1));

    }
}
```

`Optional.orElse()` looks a lot like an `if` in disguise though...

Comment: Nice. I was thinking about adding a third `Twig` class for single-child branches, but this answer gets rid of the class sprawl entirely.

Comment: On second thought, this does not work as expected: it will return 2 for a single-node tree as it treats `Optional.empty()` as being a leaf node (which must be wrong).

Comment: In JDK9 there is a `Optional.stream` method. Maybe something like `Stream.concat(left.stream(), right.stream()).map(Tree::leafCount).orElse(1)` would work?

Comment: @friendlydog That's really clever, thanks. Not using JDK9 so I tried to fix it in the "traditional" style for now. :) Does it seem right ?

Comment: Actually, I'm mistaken. It wouldn't make sense. Streams don't have `.orElse`

Comment: Bad, bad, bad! Using an Optional as field type is ugly. Class fields have to use raw types. Optional was created only for usage as return value wrapper. Is is not Serializable and using it as class field type you simply pollute your code and only create new problems rather then solve them .

Comment: You can store children as `null` if missing and use `Optional.ofNullable()` within that method. But you can't rely on both `left` and `right` children being present for every non-leaf node.

Answer (score 0):

Adding extra function and extra variable to determine the type of node.

This assume an NonEmpty node having two Empty nodes as children is leaf, other condition are consider as not leaf.

```
abstract class Tree {
    abstract int count();
    abstract int type();
}

class Empty extends Tree {
    public int type() {
        return 1;   
    }

    public int count() {
        return 0;   
    }
}

class NonEmpty extends Tree {

    private final int val;
    private final Tree left;
    private final Tree right;
    private final int type;

    public NonEmpty(int val, Tree left, Tree right) {
        this.val   = val;
        this.left  = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.type  = left.type() * right.type();
    }

    public int type() {
        return 0;   
    }

    public int count() {
        return (1-this.type) * (left.count() + right.count()) + this.type;
    }

}
```